# Nginx - How do I prevent wordpress from hijacking all locations so I can use some for angular x?

Tags: angular, wordpress, nginx

A little background, I basically want some of the site to operate via wordpress and other parts to operate via angular 7.

So `website.com` will go to the wordpress homepage and `website.com/signin` will go to the angular website. Is this possible? I've been playing around with an nginx setup and this is what I have so far. Unfortunately, it forces everything to go through the wordpress site so when I hit `/signin`, I get a wordpress generated 404.

The routing is more complex than that, the ideal scenario would be to whitelist certain path starts and route those to angular while routing anything else to wordpress (for that relatively universal 404). For example,

```
website.com/signin         --
website.com/users/:id        |
website.com/signout          |- all of these route to angular
website.com/otherModels/:id  |
website.com/another        --

website.com/everything-else-goes-to-wordpress
```

I can get either wordpress or angular to work, but they seem to be using competing index files. My angular uses index.html and wordpress uses index.php (while, if I'm not mistaken, hijacking all other calls within its directory). Here are the nginx files I use for wordpress:

```
server {
    root /var/www/website.com;
    index index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name website.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_buffers 8 16k; # increase the buffer size for PHP-FTP
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k; # increase the buffer size for PHP-FTP
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

And angular:

```
server {
    root /path/to/angular-project/dist;
    index index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name website.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri$args /index.html;
    }
}
```

I can obviously add the locations to the other files, but when I do, whichever is setup in `location / {}` works whereas the other doesn't. For example, if I change the wordpress file to contain:

```
location = /signin {
    root /path/to/angular-project/dist; // I've tried using alias as well
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri$args /index.html;
}
```

Nothing happens. I still get my wordpress 404 (instead of the angular site). I can change the above snippet to `location = /signin { return 404; }` and I get an nginx 404, so I know the location is working correctly. In fact, I get an nginx 404 error up until I add `/index.html` to the end of the `try_files` line. This leads me to believe that the `try_files /index.html` is somehow not getting redirected to (hijacked by) wordpress. This happens in the reverse as well. Between angular/wordpress, hichever is setup in `location / {}` determines a 404 for locations that are supposed to be defined by the other.

Is there a way to prevent wordpress/angular from hijacking all "index" files?

Comment: Nginx processes URIs and needs to decide which ones belong to Angular and which ones belong to WordPress. At least one of your applications needs to have something unique in the URI (like `/blog/`) or you will need to provide a map of every URI the Angular app will ever use.

Comment: That makes sense, but nginx should route match based on the locations I provided, especially if I use `location = /route` or `location ^~ /start/`. So in reality, I should only have to define a few routes (for now). That will inevitably grow, but by the time that gets unmanageable, we'll be off wordpress so I'll be able to route everything through angular.

Comment: There is one other location you will need: `location = /index.html { ... }`. The internal redirection performed by the last parameter of the `try_files` statement, also needs to be handled correctly.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Thanks, this at least solves the 404. Now I just need to figure out how to map all the js files that get built into dist. Nginx still attempts to pull those from the wordpress location (I believe since they're getting a 404 now that I can get past the index.html 404).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm piggy backing off of [Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith)'s comments. Basically what was happening (as far as I can tell), is that Wordpress was using everything I defined in my `index`, which included `index.html` (the root for angular projects). In order to avoid this, I specifically told nginx to route index.html requests to angular.

```
location = index.html {
    root /path/to/angular-project/dist; // I've tried using alias as well
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

This forced anything routing specifically through index.html to get routed to my angular app. Once I made this change, I was able to direct specific links to angular while leaving the default (aka anything else) routing to wordpress. But, there were other errors that this caused. All js/css/etc files were still getting routed through wordpress. This is what I did (although there's probably an easier way).

```
location ~* .(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|svg|otf)$ {
    root /path/to/angular-project/dist;
    try_files $uri @wordpress_files;
}
location @wordpress_files {
    root /var/www/website.com;
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri$args;
}
```

After doing that, my site would attempt to find the specific file in angular first. If that failed, it would load wordpress's version. This doesn't handle if files have the same name, but if that's the case, they should hopefully be the same version and therefore should be safe to load either.